# Google Timeline Chart: Invalid data row# start>end?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to make the bar of Google Timeline Chart located as one row,but start date and end date of my data is all overlapping.

then, I found the code that can change the enddate of previous row like

*Noted :My label column number is 5 and 6
| startdate column number is 12| and end date column number is 13*

```js
for (var row = 1; row < data1.getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
  //if the previous one has the same label  
  if (data1.getValue(row - 1, 5) == data1.getValue(row, 5) && data1.getValue(row - 1, 6) == data1.getValue(row, 6)) {
    // if the previous end date is greater than the start date of current row
    if (data1.getValue(row - 1, 13) > data1.getValue(row, 12)) {
      // set the previous end date to the start date of current row 
      data1.setValue(row - 1, 13, data1.getValue(row, 12))
    }
  }
}
```

but when I run this code,I got an error

> Invalid data at row #9: start(Sat Aug 13 2005 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)) > end(Tue Jan 01 1991 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)).

and my data looks like

[image]

underline red is the row which in the error

anyone know what the problem is?
thanks.

Comment: the start date cannot be before the end date (2005 - 1991)...

Comment: @WhiteHat So that means I can't put it in one row if the date is overlapping (I can't change startdate or enddate as well because I wanna show the data from start to current) / maybe I have to change the order of country

Comment: try sorting data by country, start date, end date...

Comment: @WhiteHat yes!! that works,thanks for help who such a fool like me..